# Improve the formatting of an HTML form that submits to email without JavaScript?

Tags: html, forms, email

I have a simple form that lives on an internal website to help with support requests. It submits to email and fills out some of the details to help standardize the process. The problem is that I have to use html only to do this, since I don't own the page that this is on and the admin will not allow me to add or invoke javascript/php/etc. Since it is internal only and I don't have security concerns, I think my solution is mostly fine:

```
<div id="main">
<h2 id="register">Register</h2>
<p>Please fill out this questionnaire:</p>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Support Request" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Application Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="Application Name"><br>
  Server(s): <br>
<input type="text" name="Server"><br>
  Comments: <br>
<input type="text" name="Comments"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send ">
<input type="reset" value="Reset ">
</form>
</div>
```

This produces the email 90% how I would like, but I want the format to be, instead of like this:

```
>     Application Name=AppName 
>     Server=ServerName 
>     Comments=I need it NOW
```

More like this:

```
>     Application Name: AppName 
>     Server: ServerName 
>     Comments: I need it NOW
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Not much you can do without at least some client-side javascript.

Comment: [mailto form actions are hideously unreliable](https://web.archive.org/web/20191008030920/http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html), **do not use them**, find a server-side solution and use an HTTP URL instead.